# Copy/extract part of a File path?

Tags: delphi, filenames, filepath

How can I copy/extract part of a File path?

For example, say if I have this path: **D:\Programs\Tools\Bin\Somefile.dat**

how could I copy/extract it to make it like this:

**C:\Users\Bin\Somefile.dat**

or

**C:\Users\Tools\Bin\Somefile.dat**

or

**C:\Users\Programs\Tools\Bin\Somefile.dat**

Notice that the examples above are taking part of the original path, and changing it to another directory. I think this is called Expand name or something maybe??

PS, I already know about ExtractFileName and ExtractFilePath etc, the path anyway could be dynamic in that it wont be a hard coded path, but ever changing, so these functions are likely no good.

Thanks.

Comment: I fail to see the similarity between the transformations. There are lots of different solutions, using `System.Pos()` and `System.Copy()`, or using `TStringList.DelimitedText`, or using a Regex. Please explain the required transformations!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick implementation that returns the TAIL of a path, including the specified number of elements. There's also a bit of demo of how to use it, and the results are exactly the ones you requested. Unfortunately I don't fully understand what transformations you're after: this might be exactly what you're after, or it might be something entirely wrong, that just happens to produce a result that looks like your sample:

```
program Project25;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

function ExtractPathTail(const OriginalPath:string; const PathElemCount:Integer):string;
var i, start, found_delimiters: Integer;
begin
  start := 0;
  found_delimiters := 0;
  for i:=Length(OriginalPath) downto 1 do
    if OriginalPath[i] = '\' then
    begin
      Inc(found_delimiters);
      if found_delimiters = PathElemCount then
      begin
        start := i;
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  if start = 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('Original path is too short, unable to cut enough elements from the tail.') // mangled English to help SO's code formatter
  else
    Result := System.Copy(OriginalPath, start+1, MaxInt);
end;

const SamplePath = 'D:\Programs\Tools\Bin\Somefile.dat';

begin
  try
    WriteLn('C:\Users\' + ExtractPathTail(SamplePath, 2)); // prints: C:\Users\Bin\Somefile.dat
    WriteLn('C:\Users\' + ExtractPathTail(SamplePath, 3)); // prints: C:\Users\Tools\Bin\Somefile.dat
    WriteLn('C:\Users\Programs\' + ExtractPathTail(SamplePath, 3)); // prints: C:\Users\Programs\Tools\Bin\Somefile.dat
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the ExtractFileName function? all built in for you. Depending on where your paths/files are coming from of course, you may need the ExtractFilePath, or other related functions.

Comment: I already know ExtractFileName and ExtractFilePath etc, I wont always know the path or length, so these functions probably wont do it unless I know the path.

Comment: Length? length of what? if you dont know where you're going to copy the file to, I dont understand the question. What exactly are you trying to do? Find the file?

Comment: by length I mean i dont know how many folders and subfolders the path could contain.

Comment: I never implied you did, that was the whole point of extract path and filenames.. you get the path from wherever the path is entered, to send the files to, and then filename from where ever the file was selected...

Answer (score 0):

try using the PathAppend and PathExtractElements functions

Comment: thanks, you should mention this is in JclFileUtils.pas, I had to search it. I will look at this functions.

Comment: Sorry! :)  there are some more helpful functions if you search for **Path** in the JCL help